# create-react-app with -–template typescript not creating .tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I decided to use React JS with TypeScript. Doing a simple hello world project. Referring two books, and they both suggest the following. Brand new project, not upgrading or any of those scenarios. Starting fresh.

```
npx create-react-app try-react -–template typescript
```

That works fine.

But, the files, they still have the .js extension. In the book, one of them has a screenshot, it is already with .tsx extension.

I have looked at this link, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/. It says,

```
If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
```

So, I removed the global install. tried again.

Same thing. no files with .tsx extension. The book author does not mention anything about having to rename these files manually.

So, my question is,

1. is the template not supposed to automatically set all extensions to .tsx?
2. is the only way to do this is to manually change from .js to .tsx?
3. do we always do this, and that is indeed the norm. Perhaps, the book author did do it manually but forgot to include it in the instructions?

Comment: Can you run ```npx create-react-app --version``` and post the output?

Comment: npx create-react-app --version
npx: installed 67 in 4.928s
4.0.1

Comment: Hmm, that is the latest version of ```create-react-app```. Somehow, I am not able to regenerate this issue on my system. Can you try using ```yarn create-react-app my-app --typescript``` ? I know any of this doesn't answer the questions you have asked, I am digging around a bit myself. Once done, I'll answer your questions

Comment: @DamodarHegde thank you. Further, what I found out on my own (my guess) is that, create react app is no longer supposed to create ts files and manually changing is the only way (again, my guess).

Comment: Really? I was able to get ```tsx``` files with ```yarn```. I tried it again after reading your comment and it still gave me typescript files.

Comment: @DamodarHegde I just spent half an hour trying to get yarn to work on windows. cannot get it to work with visual studio code. I am going to stick with npx right now. dont want to use yarn right now. sorry. really sorry. I have to focus on react learning right now. cannot get side tracked with yarn issues :)

Comment: Sure :) No need to be sorry. Do what works for you :)

Comment: I had the same issue with npx command but yarn worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. What solved it for me:

`npm install cra-template-typescript`

For some reason the template was not there for me.

Comment: I think they have updated the way typescript is used lately so its easier. Probably enough people complained

Comment: I just had this issue yesterday on the latest tools, not sure

Answer (score 6):

In my case what solved it was installing the typescript template **globally**

```
npm install -g cra-template-typescript
```

Once I did that, I ran

```
npx create-react-app client-app --template typescript
```

Ant it worked. All script files where **.tsx**

Answer (score 2):

Providing an independent answer because I don't have the reputation to comment on or edit @ChrisPabst's answer.

I'm also using the David Choi book, and stumbled across this question for the same reason as the parent...I couldn't get --template typescript to generate typescript files. ChrisPabst's answer got me to look more closely at the difference between commands pasted from the book, and commands directly entered, and sure enough, here's a paste from Chapter 5:

`npx create-react-app class-components -–template typescript`

Zoom in on the template hyphens, re-pasted here:

`-–`

Now I type in the hyphens directly:

`--`

Now let's re-paste the hyphens from the question text itself:

`-–`

It definitely looks like the first set, not the second.

EDIT: If you get the ASCII values of the above pasted characters (e.g. fire up a python interpreter, and then type `ord("–")` for each character, the pasted text will give you

45 and 8211

while entering it yourself is 45 and 45.)

tl;dr : If you're using the David Choi book "Full-Stack React, TypeScript, and Node", all of the advice above about `cra-react-template` is a complete red herring. Paste the command, but before you press enter, go back and type in the double-hyphens yourself. A typescript template will be generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I believe the book in question is Full-Stack React, TypeScript, and Node by David Choi. I too am learning React from this book, and I also ran into this problem. This issue was not actually in the environment, but in the command itself (which you can see in the original question).

If you are reading the book online, and copy the command to set up a new React app, you get

`npx create-react-app hooks-components –template typescript`

But the book for some reason has a non-ascii dash instead of the correct `--`. So the template arg is ignored.

What I kept missing was this error.

`npm ERR! arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably invalid: –template`

So yes it is supposed to work; No you don't have to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try two things:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

or

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

This should work as of today.